# Video encoding libraries for Windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video-encoding

ffmpeg is a widely used cross-platform library. But it doesn't support Visual C++, meaning you have to jump through hoops.

And considering they say the following, it's clear they don't give $0.02 about MSVC users and that makes me uncomfortable for a serious project.. how can one of the most widely used cross-platform libraries not support the most common toolset on the most common OS?

> There have been efforts to make FFmpeg compatible with MSVC++ in the
>   past. However, they have all been rejected as too intrusive,
>   especially since MinGW does the job adequately. None of the core
>   developers work with MSVC++ and thus this item is low priority. Should
>   you find the silver bullet that solves this problem, feel free to
>   shoot it at us.
>
> We strongly recommend you to move over from MSVC++ to MinGW tools.

It seems unlikely all the Windows developers are doing all this messing about, so are there more Windows-friendly libraries around?

Comment: Yup: Windows Media, DirectShow, Microsoft Media Foundation. These are designed to be used with Visual Studio. FFmpeg is less of a cross-platform library, than a *nix library with a Windows port.

Comment: Those are core system APIs not libraries, surely? You'd have to do a ton of low-level stuff compared to using a framework such as ffmpeg?

Comment: Microsoft describes the DirectShow Codecs as libraries, and they are implemented as libraries. I'd say it's rather straight forward: If you want to use the MS toolchain, use the MS-recommended way to encode media. On a more constructive note: Most ffmpeg consumers I know of, run ffmpeg as an external process, not as an in-process library.

Comment: However you couldn't _get_ more platform dependent (we want to have Win/Mac support and use wx), _and_ I have some concerns about using DShow in the same app as OGL? Regarding ffpeg as a separate process, indeed this would be simpler but for in-app recording my understanding is you have to save every frame as an image before encoding, which may be infeasible.

Comment: However you couldn't get **more** platform dependent than using Visual Studio instead of gcc.

Comment: That's simply incorrect. Every single other cross-platform library I use supports Visual Studio. Only a Linux zealot would suggest good cross-platform compatibility is achieved by saying "yeah you just need to change your compiler from the one virtually every commercial Windows developer uses". GCC isn't platform independent, it's a Linux project which has a Windows port.

Answer (score 0):

Use Expression Encoder SDK. It is extremely easy to use with VS, both c++ and c#. The free version has enough presets to start with, but if you are working on a commercial product better buy a license.